# Lazy initialization using single check idiom

Tags: java, volatile, lazy-initialization, effective-java

In Item 71 in 'Effective Java, Second Edition' the Double-check idiom and the single-check idiom are introduced for lazily instantiating instance fields.

**Double-check idiom**

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
  FieldType result = field;
  if (result == null) {
    synchronized(this) {
      result == field;
      if (result == null)
        field = result = computeFieldValue();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Single-check idiom**

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
  FieldType result = field;
  if (result == null) {
    field = result = computeFieldValue();
  }
  return result;
}
```

In the double-check idiom Joshua states, that the **result** variable is used to make sure that the volatile **field** is only read once, which improves performance. This I understand, however I don't see why we need it in the single-check idiom, since we only read **field** once anyway.

Comment: Double-check is obsolete since there are multi-processor environments:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: @alfasin: this IBM article is obsolete. With the Java 5 memory model and guarantees over volatile fields, the above double-check idiom is OK.

Comment: memory model is not the only problem here, start reading at "A JIT compiler would see an optimization opportunity here..."

Comment: @alfasin: this article is from 2002. Eleven years ago. Things have changed since then. Don't you think Josh Bloch knows what he's talking about?

Comment: @JBNizet is that a way of arguing ? should I count on what someone said/wrote ? personally, I like to understand the reasons behind things rather than "count on someone's word" even if it's a guru...

Comment: Then why do you count on an article written by some IBMer in 2002? The Java 5 memory model brings guarantees that the old one didn't bring, and that make this idiom safe. Read the spec if you don't believe me and Josh Bloch.

Comment: @JBNizet I count on code examples + explanations - not on the "title" of an article. I know that `volatile` changed on Java 5. I was saying  that JIT compiler optimization might break the safety of double-check implementation. If you know that this is no longer true - I'd love to educate myself and would appreciate a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the single-check idiom, without the result variable you'd still be reading it twice; once for the null check and once for the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following implementation of lazy evaluation:

```
@ThreadSafe
class MyClass {
    private static class MyClassHelper {
       public static final MyClass helper = new MyClass();
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return MyClassHelper.helper;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the proper method for lazy initialize room. While other methods can achieve the same effect, here you rely on the Classloader's for an elegant solution. Though I would make helper field final.

Comment: It doesn't compile because of he uses "HelperHolder.helper" instead of "MyClassHelper.holder", just a small change/typo.

Comment: @JBNizet I wrote it on notepad... fixed. Thanks Jared!
 :)

Comment: Nothing, static fields are fine.
Just wanted to mention that, since I was initially talking about lazy evaluation on instance fields.